# Trigger for inserting/updating columns is not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert-update

I have created a `trigger` in Oracle. What I want to this, whether a new row is inserted or any existing row is updated I want to `Insert/Update` particular column based on some conditions respectively.

Below is my trigger for the same, but it's giving me some error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_UPD_RRSOC_ZONAL_NAME
BEFORE UPDATE ON TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN      
 IF NEW.SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME = 'ABC' then ZONE_NAME = 'North';
 IF NEW.SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME = 'XYZ 'then ZONE_NAME = 'South';
END;
```

What is wrong, as I am getting error as:

> Error(4,48): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

Comment: You'd need to refer to the `:new` pseudorecord with a leading colon.  I'm not sure what your `IF` statement is supposed to mean-- you're not comparing `:new.slp_zonal_head_name` to anything.  Assuming your intention is to assign a value to `:new.zone_name`, you'd use the `:=` operator for assignment.  The `=` operator is for comparisons.

Comment: @JustinCave: what I want is, whenever an existing row is updated i want to update `:new.zone_name`. I added `IF` because, I will be having 2-3 more conditions. Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `zone_name` is a column in the `TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO` table, it sounds like you want something like this.  Note that

- References to the `:new` pseudorecord need to be prefixed with the colon `:`,
- The assignment operator is `:=` not `=`,
- If you want to change the value of the `zone_name` column, you'd assign a value to `:new.zone_name`
- An `IF` statement needs an `END IF`.  You could use `ELSIF` branches as well rather than duplicating the `IF statements.

So the trigger body would be something like this

```
BEGIN      
 IF :NEW.SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME = 'ABC' then :new.ZONE_NAME := 'North'; end if;
 IF :NEW.SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME = 'XYZ' then :new.ZONE_NAME := 'South'; end if;
END;
```

Or more concisely, use a `case` statement rather than a series of `IF` statements

```
BEGIN
  :new.zone_name := case :NEW.SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME
                         when 'ABC' then 'North'
                         when 'XYZ' then 'South'
                      end;
END;
```

Comment: thanks justin for prompt answer, just one more question.. I want to implement this for both `INSERT` and `UPDATE`

Comment: @hud - OK.  Then define the trigger to fire on `INSERT OR UPDATE` rather than on `UPDATE`.

Comment: yes done.. added like this `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO`